# How to add "fallback" value to optional function argument in flow?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, types, flowtype

I have following function utalising flow types

```
  push = (pathname: string, data?: Object) => {
    const history = [...this.state.history, pathname];
    this.setState({
      history,
      pathname,
      data
    });
  };
```

In normal javascript I would be able to do something like `(pathname, data = null)` where null would be used for data if it wasn't provided, but I can't figure out syntax for this when using flow types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let push = (pathname: string, data?: Object = {a: 1}) => {
    // ...
};
```

In addition, you can also use default values with destructuring together:

```
type Arg = { prop: number };
const func = ({ prop = 1 }: Arg) => prop;
```